# Keeping RTF formatting when moving files

Tags: perl, rtf

I have been able to tokenize a RTF document and then print it to another RTF document. My question is whether or not it is possible to keep the original formatting from the first document (font, font color, background color). There are somethings that are randomly colored in the document so keeping the formatting is important.

Here it the tokenizer code :

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use RTF::Writer;
use Data::Dumper;
use RTF::Tokenizer;

die "usage: $0 input output\n" unless @ARGV == 2;

my $infile = shift;
my $outfile = shift;

my $tokenizer = RTF::Tokenizer->new();
$tokenizer->read_file($infile);

my ( $token_type, $argument, $parameter );

{
# reduce bogus warnings
no warnings 'uninitialized';


# get past the header
( $token_type, $argument, $parameter ) =
$tokenizer->get_token() until
($token_type eq 'control' and $argument eq 'par');
}

my @final;
while ($token_type ne 'eof'){
( $token_type, $argument, $parameter ) = $tokenizer->get_token();
push @final, $argument if $token_type eq 'text';
}

my $rtf = RTF::Writer->new_to_file($outfile);
my @sorted = sort {
my @fields_a = split / / , $a;
my @fields_b = split / /, $b;
chomp($a, $b);
$fields_a[0] cmp $fields_b[0];
} @final;

$rtf->prolog;
$rtf->print(\@sorted);
$rtf->close;
```

This is what im inputing

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl;\red255\green0\blue0;
\red0\green0\blue255;}
\cf1 145747.2545  
\cf0 134758.2545
```

and I want to output these in order with the same formating. I already made a sorting script for it

Comment: And what problem are you encountering?

Comment: It outputs a file without any formatting at all.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Writer.pod) for RTF::Writer, it looks like you need to pass scalar references to `print()` to signal that your string contains escaped RTF sequences.

Comment: ive also tried   `foreach(@sorted){rtf->print("$_\n")}` wouldnt that be a scalar reference?

Comment: No, there are no references there.

Comment: In your original code, you're passing an array reference, which is apparently fine, but you still need scalar references for things that are supposed to be RTF commands. Read the docs I linked.

Comment: @MattJacob I will check it out. Dont know much about scalar references

Comment: There's a manual page for that, too: [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Comment: @MattJacob now it prints all the formating at the top but doesn actually apply it. `$rtf->print(\@tokens);`

Comment: Yep, that looks the same as your original code. Probably still no scalar references.

Comment: @MattJacob yeah youre right... I cant fiegure how to implement them correctly

Comment: @miked23: *"lol that is my post too"* I think that was **toolic's** point. It is rude of you to cross-post the same question to multiple sites without saying clearly that you have done so. People could be working on a solution for you without being aware that aware that your question has already been answered elsewhere. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [RTF::Writer](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Writer.pod), sequences of RTF commands need to be passed to the `print()` method as [scalar references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use RTF::Writer;

my $rtf = RTF::Writer->new_to_handle(*STDOUT);

while (<DATA>) {
    $rtf->print(\$_);
}

$rtf->close;

__DATA__
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl;\red255\green0\blue0;
\red0\green0\blue255;}
\cf1 145747.2545
\cf0 134758.2545
```

I'm not familiar with the RTF spec, so I don't know whether newlines are desirable here or not.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl;\red255\green0\blue0;
\red0\green0\blue255;}
\cf1 145747.2545
\cf0 134758.2545
```

If you just pass a scalar to `print()` rather than a scalar *reference*, it looks like some escaping is performed:

```
\'7b\'5crtf1\'5cansi\'5cdeff0\'7b\'5cfonttbl\'7b\'5cf0 Times New Roman;\'7d\'7d
\line \'7b\'5ccolortbl;\'5cred255\'5cgreen0\'5cblue0;
\line \'5cred0\'5cgreen0\'5cblue255;\'7d
\line \'5ccf1 145747\'2e2545
\line \'5ccf0 134758\'2e2545
\line
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation I will try to implement this